# How count Rows of CSV file Efficiently in Java

Tags: java, sql, database, csv, jdbc

I have developed a code which opens a CSV file and counts the number of rows using a for loop, but I feel this method is not efficient and causes several delays.

- `TargetFile.mdb` has 120 rows
- `report.csv` has 11000 rows

If I use this method the code needs to run `120*11000=1320000 times` to count each resource count. Here is my code:

Here is new and working code which count rows efficiently by Xavier Delamotte:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Table;

public class newcount {

    public static class ValueKey{
        String mdmId;
        String pgName;

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((mdmId == null) ? 0 : mdmId.hashCode());
            result = prime * result
                + ((pgName == null) ? 0 : pgName.hashCode());
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            ValueKey other = (ValueKey) obj;
            if (mdmId == null) {
                if (other.mdmId != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!mdmId.equals(other.mdmId))
                return false;
            if (pgName == null) {
                if (other.pgName != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!pgName.equals(other.pgName))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        public ValueKey(String mdmId, String pgName) {
            super();
            this.mdmId = mdmId;
            this.pgName = pgName;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException,Throwable{


        Integer count;

        String MDMID,NAME,PGNAME,PGTARGET,TEAM;

        Table RESOURCES = Database.open(new File("C:/STATS/TargetFile.mdb")).getTable("RESOURCES");
        int pcount = RESOURCES.getRowCount();


        String csvFilename = "C:\\MDMSTATS\\APEX\\report.csv";
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename));
        List<String[]> content = csvReader.readAll();
        Map<ValueKey, Integer> csvValuesCount = new HashMap<ValueKey, Integer>();
        for (String[] rowcsv  : content) {
            ValueKey key = new ValueKey(rowcsv[6], rowcsv[1]);
            count = csvValuesCount.get(key);
            csvValuesCount.put(key,count == null ? 1: count + 1);

        }

        //int count = 0;
        // Taking 1st resource data
        for (int i = 0; i < pcount-25; i++) {
            Map<String, Object> row = RESOURCES.getNextRow();
            TEAM = row.get("TEAM").toString();
            MDMID = row.get("MDM ID").toString();
            NAME = row.get("RESOURCE NAME").toString();
            PGNAME = row.get("PG NAME").toString();
            PGTARGET = row.get("PG TARGET").toString();
            int PGTARGETI = Integer.parseInt(PGTARGET);
            Integer countInteger = csvValuesCount.get(new ValueKey(MDMID, PGNAME));
            count = countInteger == null ? 0: countInteger;
            System.out.println(NAME+"\t"+PGNAME+"\t"+count);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: all i want to do is to count resource count by using sql query on csv file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to read the csv file only one time, and to count the occurence of the key composed by mdmId and pgName.

If you have guava, you could have used a `MultiSet<ValueKey>` http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html instead  of the `Map<ValueKey,Integer>`

edit: and to use the ValueKey class you need to  put in another file or declare it static.

class ValueKey:

```
    public static class ValueKey{
        String mdmId;
        String pgName;
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((mdmId == null) ? 0 : mdmId.hashCode());
            result = prime * result
                    + ((pgName == null) ? 0 : pgName.hashCode());
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            ValueKey other = (ValueKey) obj;
            if (mdmId == null) {
                if (other.mdmId != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!mdmId.equals(other.mdmId))
                return false;
            if (pgName == null) {
                if (other.pgName != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!pgName.equals(other.pgName))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        public ValueKey(String mdmId, String pgName) {
            super();
            this.mdmId = mdmId;
            this.pgName = pgName;
        }
    }
```

your method:

```
    Table RESOURCES = Database.open(new File("TargetFile.mdb")).getTable("RESOURCES");
    int pcount = RESOURCES.getRowCount();

    String csvFilename = "C:\\STATS\\APEX\\report.csv";
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename));
    List<String[]> content = csvReader.readAll();
    Map<ValueKey, Integer> csvValuesCount = new HashMap<ValueKey, Integer>();
    for (String[] rowcsv  : content) {
        ValueKey key = new ValueKey(rowcsv[6], rowcsv[1]);
        Integer count = csvValuesCount.get(key);
        csvValuesCount.put(key,count == null ? 1: count + 1);

    }

    int count = 0;
    // Taking 1st resource data
    for (int i = 0; i < pcount; i++) {
        Map<String, Object> row = RESOURCES.getNextRow();
        TEAM = row.get("TEAM").toString();
        MDMID = row.get("MDM ID").toString();
        NAME = row.get("RESOURCE NAME").toString();
        PGNAME = row.get("PG NAME").toString();
        PGTARGET = row.get("PG TARGET").toString();
        int PGTARGETI = Integer.parseInt(PGTARGET);
        Integer countInteger = csvValuesCount.get(new ValueKey(MDMID, PGNAME));
        count = countInteger == null ? 0: countInteger;
    }
```

Comment: this also have two loops [for (String[] rowcsv  : content)] will also run 11000 times for each resource and now updated the code nnow csv file is readed once

Comment: it looks it will work i will let you know after adding this to my whole code :)

Comment: The Value Key class needs to be static.

Comment: OMG your code is super fast :) i want to learn how it is done tell me or give me any link to study

Answer (score 0):

Dear friend I suggest you to use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

I think it can satisfy your requirement ;)

Comment: i am using open csv see code again and yes it can satisfy but i think running a code 1320000 times is not a good idea and it takes long time for it

Comment: Dear H4SN, it's not clear from your code that you're using OpenCSV, anyway, the Xaviar Delmotte's solution is good, try it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Read the CSV first, make a Set of field 6 values, and use that to update the count.  This should be pretty fast.

```
//open csv and make lookup set
Set<String> mdmids = new HashSet<String>() 
String[] rowcsv = null;
String csvFilename = "C:\\STATS\\APEX\\report.csv";
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename));
List content = csvReader.readAll();

for (Object object : content) {
    rowcsv = (String[]) object;             
       mdmids.add(rowcsv[6])
}
Table RESOURCES = Database.open(new File("TargetFile.mdb")).getTable("RESOURCES");
pcount = RESOURCES.getRowCount();
count = 0;
// Taking 1st resource data
for (i = 0; i < pcount; i++){
Map<String, Object> row = RESOURCES.getNextRow();                            
    TEAM = row.get("TEAM").toString();
MDMID = row.get("MDM ID").toString();
NAME = row.get("RESOURCE NAME").toString();
PGNAME = row.get("PG NAME").toString();
PGTARGET = row.get("PG TARGET").toString();
int PGTARGETI = Integer.parseInt(PGTARGET);

// use lookup set
if(mdmids.contains(MDMID)) {
    count++;
}
}
```

Comment: how count will return row count of 1st MDMID??

Comment: The csv will get opened, and a set of mdmids in the csv (column 6) will be built up.  Then the csv's done and can get garbage collected.

Going through the DB rows, it will use the set to see if there's a matching mdmid.  This is a hash operation and pretty fast for only 11000 entries.

Comment: this code will just incrtment count if if(mdmids.contains(MDMID)) not the total count for particular MDMID